# In dualboot, make ubuntu boot option the default during boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-order

Hello I ak dualbooting windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04.
I have gone through  a great deal of trouble trying to get the grub to show up but couldn't. Finally i kind of got a way. For me to access it, i have to press F9 choose boot option as ubuntu, located at the bottom of the list. How can i boot to grub directly without going through F9 and boot options. 
Please help.
Have tried moving boot order to custom....bla bla bla but nothing is working. 
I even used the option  of copying the ubuntu grubx64.efi to ...Microsoft/boot/ and renaming it to bootmgfw.efi but it didn't work.
Help me please.
Thanks

Comment: The mention of the "F9" key makes me suspect it's a HP? Am I right? There could be problem with some models from some years ago when dual-booting, even if Ubuntu is installed in the correct UEFI mode. Have you tried to select "Ubuntu" as the first boot? What happens? (This is assuming you installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode because otherwise THAT is the problem).

Comment: What brand/model system? Some like HP only work with updated UEFI and changing order within UEFI, not from efibootmgr (which grub uses when installing, also). Some will not boot anything but "Windows Boot Manger" by description. But may boot the fallback entry. See: Sony, HP & others workarounds:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: I'm using HP folio 9480M.

Comment: Actually when i boot first it shows me "system boot order not found. Initializing defaults."Then it goes for an infinite loop. It's only through f9 that i can boot to any OS